# Spring property misread on Docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have this Spring Boot app, which runs fine locally (from -jar as well as from `docker-compose`). However, when I try to run it in `docker-compose` on a different machine, it gives me this Exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'delete': For input string: "'0"
```

That's the faulty method:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${sprint.bot.localDbRemoveTime.cron}")
private void delete() { ... }
```

And here is the faulty property (`application.properties`):

```
sprint.bot.localDbRemoveTime.cron = 0 0 5 * * ?
```

Has anyone encountered something like this? I'll just add that I have different versions of Docker and docker-compose on these machines respectively...

Comment: do you maybe have some external config that overwrites the value from application.properties?

Comment: Are you setting the cron property in the docker compose file env?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli To both your questions the answer is: NO

Comment: Your property is `sprint.bot.localDbRemoveTime.cron` in your properties file it is `sprint.bot.extDbRemoveTime.cron`. So unless you have some magic somewhere turning one into the other it won't work.

Comment: @daniu To both your questions the answer is: NO

Comment: Yes I have some magic :)

Comment: Without knowing what you do to shoehorn one into the other it is impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum What do you mean? Isn't it self-explanatory? What do you need to know?

Comment: That was before you modified the question and make the properties match. Nonetheless something is overriding the value (environment property, other contributed `application.properties` etc.). And it does so by a quoted range. Make sure that there is only a single file (don't mix properties and yaml) or that there is accidentally something in the docker environment. You could enable debug to see where the value gets resolved from.